# I have a chirping sound in my house that moves around

Tags: pest-control, noise-reduction

It is not the smoke detector. We have just had rain and there was a ton of tree frogs out front in the trees. Could a tree frog be in my house making that chirping noise? (The chirping sound moves around the living room only.) And, if so how do I get rid of him.....it's just me & my daughter. We are afraid of them. I am because of their feet....those sticky things.

Comment: Can you borrow a cat?

Comment: Could be a cricket. We sometimes get one that comes inside.

Comment: House geckos also make a sound similar to a bark or chirp when they get trapped inside and can't find any friends.

Answer (score 1):

> **Could a tree frog be in my house?**

Based on your question, yes. It could also be some other relatively benign creature like a cricket.

> **how do I get rid of him?**

You could call a pest eradicator but these sorts of creature are usually easy to catch

Many small critters can be trapped one of these ways:

Don whatever protective gear makes you more comfortable and confident (e.g. long plastic gloves)

Locate them by sound, this may take time but should be doable if you stand still.

[image]

Take the cardboard tube from a roll of kitchen paper and fold one end securely shut (maybe tape or staple it). Place it along a corner between floor and wall with open end towards creature. Small scurrying creatures will head for the safety of darkness and enter the tube. You can then pick the tube up with the open end uppermost and relocate your captive to where it belongs.

[image]

Take a medium to large clear plastic cup (or similar transparent container) and place it slowly over the creature. Many dumber creatures only flee if something large and dark approaches quickly. This is a good way of catching wasps etc. I haven't tried it on crickets but I expect them to be harder. Slowly slide a stiff sheet of paper or cardboard under the inverted cup so as to fully contain the creature, then lift and remove.

Exceptions would be some mice and rats for which you need more elaborate traps. These don't chirp though. I think you can rule out anything clever or crafty.
(other than a [nephew](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/kmnr/))

> **We are afraid of them**

I don't know if it helps, but they are almost certainly much much more afraid of you and are desperate to find a way out before they die of starvation.

[image]

You can make use of their fear, open a door and stand so that you are on the opposite side of the creature to the door, the creature will be inclined to flee you and seek the safety of the outside. Turning off lights can help for some flying creatures (moths, wasps, flies, ...) that seek light.

Comment: I love this answer very helpful and also contains just plain simplistic humor...not at but with ...